# Create 600 links to separate files on google drive

Tags: urls, links

For an educational project about climate change, I need to create 600 links pointing toward 600 separate files located on google drive. I have the list of all 600 shareable URL to the files but I don't see how I can assign those URLs to the links on my wordpress website without copy/pasting them manually.

Is there a way to do this task as a automated batch?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,
André.

Comment: When you say assign them to the links on your site, can you be more specific about what you mean by that? Also plugin recommendation questions are offtopic here

Comment: Hi there, I mean I have 600 hyperlinks pointing to one file in particular. I want know to change those hyperlinks so that they point to the other 599 separate files. I just don't want to do this manually because it's tedious AND prone to error. I just basically need to understand the structure of the MySQL dump of my wordpress website. Thanks for you time! Cheers.

Comment: You don't have to understand the MySQL structure at all, if you have a page that contains 600 hyperlinks, you can copy the HTML into a code editor and do the various text operations there. Just keep in mind you will need a way to map each links text to the final URL. Without that there is no way to do this with code/machines, it would have to be by hand